# is_dir not recognizing valid directory PHP Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm putting together a slider thing for my website, which is done with Wordpress. The idea is the slider takes two arguments, a path name and a project name, and populates based on that.

Here is the function:

```php
function get_game_slider($name, $src_dir){
    $image_dir = $src_dir . $name;
    if(is_dir($image_dir)){
        /* directory is valid, search directory here */
    }
}
```

That function is located in my functions.php file. It is called from a content-template in the same directory like so:

```php
$dir = get_template_directory_uri() . "/assets/images/thumbnails/games/";
echo get_game_slider("7hours", $dir);
```

So the path name it is reporting back to me is "http://localhost/wp/wp-content/themes/ColdMetalGray/assets/images/thumbnails/games/7hours" which IS a valid directory. However, it refuses to recognize it as such.

As a test, I built this outside of my Wordpress install and it recognized it no problem (I used an absolute path instead of get_template_directory_uri()). It seems like only when I use it on a Wordpress page is it giving me this issue.

Is this something goofy with Wordpress? I've run out of ideas as to why this directory is not being viewed as a directory by is_dir().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use `get_template_directory_uri()`, use [`get_template_directory()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_template_directory), that

> Returns an absolute server path to the directory of the current theme (eg: /home/user/public_html/wp-content/themes/my_theme), not a URI.

Comment: This did it. I needed get_template_directory() for is_dir(), but then get_template_directory_uri() for actually referencing the images. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

> So the path name it is reporting back to me is
>   "http://localhost/wp/wp-content/themes/ColdMetalGray/assets/images/thumbnails/games/7hours"
>   which IS a valid directory.

`is_dir()` doesn't work over the web, it's local only. I.e., it expects a directory name, not a URI. You need to pass it the actual path of the directory on the server.

Edit: `is_dir()` does work with some stream wrappers, but HTTP isn't one of them.

Answer (score 0):

code looks right to me here are some things you can test,

1) Deactivate theme and select another theme, and then reactivate your theme to see if it makes a difference, when you reactivate it wordpress dose some stuff and gets the correct information

2) if that dose not work you can replace the get_template_directory_url() with  get_bloginfo('template_url)